# Calculate model parameters in Convolutional Neural Networks (CIFAR-10)

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

This is a function to create a model for input images stored in 4D tensors of 50000 x 32 x 32 x 3.

```
def createModel():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', 
              input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))

    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(nClasses, activation='softmax'))

return model
```

The model summary ([attached](https://www.learnopencv.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/keras-cnn-cifar-model-summary.png)) shows that the number of parameters after the first convolution should be 896 parameters but I am not certain how they got this number. I was assuming the calculation should be = 32 * 3 * 3 parameters.

Can someone tell me how to calculate the parameters per convolution layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each kernel has 28 parameters.

The kernel itself has 3 input channels * 3 width * 3 height = 27 parameters, and plus one more as a bias unit.

28 * 32 = 896

In general, you can multiple the height and width of the kernel and the number of input channels, then add 1 to get the number of parameters in a single kernel. Then multiply by the number of kernels you are convolving.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about the filter being 3D. Pardon my lack of knowledge in this area, but then for the second layer should it be 28*30? What is the general rule?

Comment: I edited my answer for a general rule

Comment: Great! So the second conv layer has (32 input channels * 3 * 3 * 32 + 1) * 32 filters = 9248 parameters! 
Your explanation was awesome :)